# conversion error from boost cpp_rational to int

Tags: c++, boost, rational-numbers

boost cpp_rational seems to convert wrong to int when the numerator and denominator have many digits.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/multiprecision/cpp_int.hpp>

using namespace boost::multiprecision;
using namespace std;

int main() {
  cpp_rational a("4561231231235/123123123123");
  std::cout << "bad convert: " << a << ' '  << 
     float(a) << ' ' << int(a) << ' ' << 
     a.convert_to<int>() << endl;
  a = (cpp_rational)"456/123";
  std::cout << "good convert: " << a << ' '  <<
     float(a) << ' ' << int(a) << ' ' << 
     a.convert_to<int>() << endl;
}
```

The output is:

```
bad convert: 651604461605/17589017589 37.0461 -3 -3
good convert: 152/41 3.70732 3 3
```

Also, attempts to convert cpp_rational to cpp_int fail to compile, e.g., using

```
cpp_int b = static_cast<cpp_int> (a);
cpp_int b = a.convert_to<cpp_int>();
```

What I want to happen is to divide and round down and never get it wrong even close to an int.

Help?  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The **[docs](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/multiprecision/doc/html/boost_multiprecision/intro.html)** say

> Conversions are also allowed:
>
> ```
> d = a; // OK, widening conversion.
> d = a * b;  // OK, can convert from an expression template too.
> ```
>
> However conversions that are inherently lossy are either declared explicit or else forbidden altogether:
>
> ```
> d = 3.14;  // Error implicit conversion from float not allowed.
> d = static_cast<mp::int512_t>(3.14);  // OK explicit construction is allowed
> ```

---

So, what you're seeing is a lossy conversion. Demonstrating that the conversion would be disallowed if you hadn't specified it *explicitly*:

```
cpp_rational a("4561231231235/123123123123");
int i   = a;        // error: cannot convert `cpp_rational` to `int` in initialization
float f = a;        // error: cannot convert `cpp_rational` to `float` in initialization
long double ld = a; // error: cannot convert `cpp_rational` to `long double` in initialization
long long   ll = a; // error: cannot convert `cpp_rational` to `long long int` in initialization
```

So, what you're doing with all the explicit casts, is telling the compiler to "Shut up; I know what I'm doing". Hence why you didn't get the warning.

Now, how to fix things: keep the division in the multi-precision domain:

```
cpp_int v = numerator(a)/denominator(a);
```

Your sample fixed: **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1f4cc815f6ca0df1)**

```
#include <boost/multiprecision/cpp_int.hpp>
#include <iostream>

using namespace boost::multiprecision;

int main() {
    cpp_rational a("4561231231235/123123123123");
    cpp_int v = numerator(a)/denominator(a);
    std::cout << "convert: " << v.convert_to<int>() << "\n";

    a = cpp_rational("456/123");
    v = numerator(a)/denominator(a);
    std::cout << "convert: " << v.convert_to<int>() << "\n";
}
```

Comment: My intuitive understanding of a lossy conversion would be that the closest (or close to the closest) representable number to the actual result would be returned.   That is what happens when the input has a small number of digits.   That is also what happens for any number of digits when the output is float.   It is not what happens when the input has many digits and the output is int.   So I also filed this as a bug report with boost and was acknowledged as a bug.  However, thanks for the numerator/denominator suggestion, which I am now using.

Comment: Well, I didn't find it specified, but apparently `cpp_rational` specifies it's conversion to int in a different way than we expect. What could I say? You should indeed take _that_ up on the boost mailing list. Thanks for the update (**PS. maybe you can add a link to the bug report?**)

Comment: Cheers. At least I arrived at the same solution. That doesn't make me feel too bad :/ I might have smelled the bug of course, well; next time :)